# Chaining of XQuery / XSLT Transformation to improve performance

Tags: performance, xslt, xquery, saxon

I have developed some XQuery scripts which I call in a chain via Saxon-CLI (bat files).
My problem is now that Saxon CLI is quite slow (because Java is slow, and Java on DotNet is even slower).

The problem is the startup time which takes some seconds (not the query execution itself). So my idea is to avoid creating new processes over and over again and just use one XSLT or XQuery process which loads the scripts and execute them.

But how to load & execute an XQuery-File in Saxon-XSLT? Is it possible?

Comment: In general you can write Java or .NET code to chain executions of XSLT and XQuery with Saxon 9 or 10. As for calling XQuery from XSLT, the function http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/fn/load-xquery-module.html is available in EE only I think, while proprietary http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/saxon/query.html and http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/saxon/compile-query.html are in PE and EE.

Comment: Another option obviously would be to look into XProc and implementations like Calabash which allow you to chain steps using XSLT and XQuery.

Comment: If you want to live on the edge you could also look into XProc 3 currently supported by MorganaXProc-IIIse 0.9.3.7-beta which is documentedd at https://www.xml-project.com/morganaxproc-iii/. XProc 3 has full support for XDM 3.1, the data model of XSLT 3 and XQuery 3.1. Its XML format is also a bit more compact and less verbose than then one of XProc 1.

Comment: XProc / Calabash sounds really interesting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly, command-line scripts that involve firing up a new Java VM for each step are NOT the way to do it!

XProc is certainly a good candidate. But I have to confess I still do a lot of this in Ant: it's old but it works.

It's also possible to control a sequence of queries and transformations from within XSLT (you can invoke queries using a Saxon extension function, but it needs Saxon-PE or higher). I don't think that's the preferred way, but it's one less technology to learn about.

There are also quite a few pipeline processors out there such as Orbeon.